# Merge multiple rows in data to show only a single row in the result

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure which takes 1 parameter, an ID number (systudentid).

The procedure returns 3 rows: a student’s academic counselor (AC), financial counselor (FC), and admissions counselor (EC) along with relevant contact information; 3 different people.

Certain students have ACs and FCs who are the same person, but the query will still return 3 rows.

```
AdvisorType|AdvisorLastName|AdvisorFirstName|(other data)|systaffID

AC          DOE             JOHN             .....        12345

AC          DOE             JOHN             .....        12345

EC          SMITH           JANE             .....        45678
```

Where in my code can I plug in the logic (and how, I'm a newbie with sql) so that when the systudentid passed to the procedure identifies a student having the same person for both AC and FC, it will display the results this way.

The advisor type is changed to "SSA" and only one of the records for the double-duty counselor is returned.

```
AdvisorType|AdvisorLastName|AdvisorFirstName|(other data)|SystaffID

SSA         DOE             JOHN             ......       12345

EC          SMITH           JANE             ......       45678
```

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT 
        SyStaffGroup.Descrip AS AdvisorType
        ,SyStaff.LastName AS AdvisorLastName
        ,SyStaff.FirstName      AS AdvisorFirstName
        ,SyStaff.Phone          AS AdvisorPhone
        ,SyStaff.Ext            AS AdvisorExtention
        ,SyStaff.eMail          AS AdvisorEMail
        ,SyStaff.SyStaffID      AS SyStaffID

    FROM SyStaff (NOLOCK)
    JOIN SyAdvisorByEnroll (NOLOCK)
      ON SyAdvisorByEnroll.SyStaffID = SyStaff.SyStaffID
    JOIN SyStaffGroup (NOLOCK)
      ON SyStaffGroup.SyStaffGroupID = SyAdvisorByEnroll.SyStaffGroupID
    JOIN AdEnroll (NOLOCK)
      ON AdEnroll.AdEnrollID = SyAdvisorByEnroll.AdEnrollID
    JOIN SyStudent (NOLOCK)
        ON AdEnroll.SyStudentID = SyStudent.SyStudentId

  WHERE 
        SyStaff.Active = 1

        --AND
        --syadvisorbyenroll.adenrollid = (
        --SELECT adenrollid from dbo.fn_student_enrollment_activeenrollmentlist (@systudentid)
        --)   

        AND adEnroll.adEnrollID IN (
              SELECT adEnrollID FROM dbo.fn_Student_Enrollment_ActiveEnrollmentList(@SyStudentID)      
        )
  AND SyAdvisorByEnroll.AdvisorModule IN ('AD','FA')
  AND SyStaffGroup.Descrip IN ('AC - Academic Counselor', 'FC - Finance Counselors', 'EC - Adm. Counselor With Reg') 

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
      'Admissions Counselor' AS AdvisorType
            ,SyStaff.LastName AS AdvisorLastName
            ,SyStaff.FirstName      AS AdvisorFirstName
            ,SyStaff.Phone          AS AdvisorPhone
            ,SyStaff.Ext            AS AdvisorExtention
            ,SyStaff.eMail          AS AdvisorEMail
            ,SyStaff.SyStaffID      AS SyStaffID
FROM systudent
      INNER JOIN AmRep ON SyStudent.AMREpID = AmREp.AMREpid
      INNER JOIN SyStaff ON SyStaff.SyStaffID = AmRep.AmRepID
WHERE Systudent.SYStudentid = @systudentid
```

Any hints or suggested methods that I can either try or Google (I've tried searching but results are a lot more useful if I knew what to look for) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a nested subquery to indicate which students have the same advisor filling multiple positions, and adjust the type selection accordingly. Here are the changed portions of your above query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (mutiples.SyStaffID IS NOT NULL) THEN 'SSA' 
    ELSE SyStaffGroup.Descrip END AS AdvisorType
    -- other columns omitted
FROM SyStaff (NOLOCK)
JOIN SyAdvisorByEnroll (NOLOCK)
  ON SyAdvisorByEnroll.SyStaffID = SyStaff.SyStaffID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SyStaffID,AdEnrollID
    FROM SyAdvisorByEnroll
    GROUP BY SyStaffID,AdEnrollID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SyStaffGroupID) > 1
) multiples
  ON multiples.SyStaffID = SyAdvisorByEnroll.SyStaffID
  AND multiples.AdEnrollID = SyAdvisorByEnroll.AdEnrollID
-- rest of query omitted
```

This might have a mistake or two, since you didn't include your table schema. The nested subquery, "multiples", contains all advisor / enrollee pairs where the advisor is in multiple groups. You left join against this and adjust the final type selection to "SSA" if there's a matching entry in the nested subquery.

An important note: as written, this will include two SSA rows for an eligible advisor / enrollee pair. However, the final results will not, because you are using a UNION in this query, which filters out duplicates, even if they're only present in one half of the union. If you change this to UNION ALL or eliminate the UNION entirely, you will need to add DISTINCT to the top of the query, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN (mutiples.SyStaffID IS NOT NULL) ...
```